# If-Else strings

Tags: java, string, if-statement

Given a string and an integer value x, return a new string with the first x characters
of the original string now at the end. Make sure there are enough characters before
attempting to move them to the end of the string.

Sample Data :
Data File: stringChopper.dat

```
apluscompsci 3
apluscompsci 5
apluscompsci 1
apluscompsci 2
apluscompsci 30
apluscompsci 4
```

Sample Output : (output needs to be exact)

```
uscompsciapl
compsciaplus
pluscompscia
luscompsciap
no can do
scompsciaplu
```

My code:

```
public class StringChopperRunner_Cavazos {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("stringChopper.dat"));

      while(fileIn.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(StringChopper.chopper(fileIn.next(), fileIn.nextInt()));
      }
   }
}

class StringChopper { 
   public static String chopper(String word1, int index) {
      if(word1.length() < index - 1){
         return "no can do";
      }
      else {
         return word1;
      } 
   }
}
```

So my question is; How can I return the String with the index number indicated if it's less than that to make sure there are ENOUGH letters printed?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`String#substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) to find different portions of a String and then concatenate them together using the `+` operator.

```
if (word1.length() < index - 1){
    return "no can do";
} else {
    return word1.substring(index) + word1.substring(0, index);
}
```

Comment: Why does this question have three upvotes (currently) when it appears to me to be nothing more than an absolute basic homework question?